# What's an adverb meaning "without willing to take 'no' for an answer"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking perhaps "insistently", but I don't think that conveighs the absoluteness of what I'm looking for and described in the question's title.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you "adamantly opposed" to something?

Comment: Does tone matter? For example, definitions I find for [*resolutely*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resolutely) don't involve words like *stubborn*, which may imply more stigma, while definitions to other words like [*pertinaciously*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pertinacious) do.

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin If you include a reference and a definition, you have a good answer.

Comment: _Intransigently_ conveys the 'refusing to negotiate' attitude.

Answer (score 1):

You might be "adamantly opposed" ("adamant" being unshakable in purpose, determination, or opinion; stone-like),

you might be "vehemently opposed" ("vehement" being zealous, ardent, impassioned),

you might be "violently opposed" ("violence" is *seldom* the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "uncompromisingly"?

> Unwilling to grant concessions or negotiate; inflexible: took an uncompromising stance during the peace talks.

Answer (score -1):

How about arrogantly or overbearingly?